# Sorting Fields In access by the time they were entered

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

What I have here is a table with some text fields. I basically put in the name of some students into a table. I got their info from forms that teachers had sent me. When I put their names into the database, I just put the names in based on which form was at the top. Does access track the actual time that a field was put in in such a way that I could sort my text fields by that so that when I give a list of what I just did to someone else, they won't have to sort through the stack of papers to make sure all of the papers are there?

I should add that I need to track this for an individual field, not just for the record. For instance, let me take this one piece of paper I have. When I get it from an outside agency, I then put it into the database with the student's name and some info. I then need to send it to the teachers for them to sign and send back to me. I am on the second part so the record had already been created, but I want to find the date that I entered the Date_signed field basically.

Comment: An important thing to learn about a relational database is that records in a table are logically unsorted. If you ever need to get data out in a particular order you need to be sure that you are storing something that can be used in an order by clause. Sometimes you may get lucky and see data that is apparently in the order you want, or in the order in which you inserted data, but you won't be "lucky" with every query, so use "order by", and store something alongside the data that you can use to rank the records.

Comment: I can do that easily when I actually create the record since there is an autonumbered ID, but when I then put data in the second time and I have to send it off, I am having the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Date/Time field with its default value = `Now()` to store the time each record is created, as already suggested.  That approach works fine when only one user can be adding new records, which sounds like your situation.

If you wish to also store the time an existing record is changed, you can do that from a form's before update event.

This example assumes a text box named `txtLast_change` which is bound to a Date/Time field in the form's record source.  The text box does not have to be visible to the user for this to work.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtLast_change = Now()
End Sub
```

Comment: This will solve my problem from here on out. It worked. Thanks!!! Yeah, I don't really care about the date I enter the record, but I do care about the date I change it so thanks!! Hopefully this solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, you set the default value of the **dtmEntered** field to **Now()**

[image]

p.s. Same answer as HugoLemos but with a pic :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a field with a date type and set default value to Now()

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned the table is already created.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, there isn't any way after-the-fact to know when data was entered in to your table, as it's not something that you captured in the first place. As you mentioned in one of your comments, you can determine the *order* in which you entered new records based on the Id, but knowing when additional data was entered would require more tracking fields.

In the future, you may want to think about a table design along these lines:

```
Column Name         Column Description
ID                  Record Id
STUDENT_ID          Student Id Number
STUDENT_FIRST_NAME  Student First Name
STUDENT_LAST_NAME   Student Last Name

     ... Other student info ...

DATE_ENTERED        Date/Time entered
DATE_SENT           Date/Time sent to teacher
DATE_SIGNED         Date/Time signed by teacher
UPDATED_DATE        Date/Time record last updated
UPDATED_BY          User that made the last update
```

If it's possible, you could always edit your table and add these datestamp columns. You'd have to allow for null values, as the previous entries wouldn't have a date/time value for some of them, but it would let you track future entries.

Comment: Thanks. After writing this, I think I just should have asked if Access tracks the time things were entered. I wanted to ask it this way because I didn't want actually confuse people with the fact that I already have date fields. However, when I get like 20 papers on one day, the date entered doesn't suffice unless the time field is included. Is there a way in Access that I could actually trigger the entry of a date in one field to input the actual time and date in another field? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chris I'm confident that there is, but I'm not familiar enough with Access to tell you how it can be done.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You got me on the right track. Kind of wish I could check your answer as well.